# Is it possible to override operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template<typename T,typename F,typename R = typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type>
R operator>>(T t,F f){
  return f(t);
} 

int inc(int i){
  return i + 1;
}
struct foo{
  int i = 0;
};
void print_foo(foo f){
  std::cout<< f.i << std::endl;
}
int get_foo_i(foo f){
  return f.i;
}

int main()
{
  foo f{1};
  f >> print_foo;//works
  int i = f >> get_foo_i;//works
  int i2 = 5 >> inc;//invalid operants
  return 0;
}
```

I created my own `>>` operator which acts like a pipe. It works for my custom types but it breaks on types that already have a `>>` operator.

Is it possible to override the >> operator globally for all types? Maybe I could do this with a namespace?

`5 pipe::>> inc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override operators for built-in data types, only for custom types.  In your example, to stream `5` into a `foo`, you would need to override the  `<<` operator instead.

Comment: *"and the custom type has to be on the left side"* [[citation needed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b47a2e9ac6767062)]

Comment: The custom type could be at either or both sides

Comment: The side of the operators depende on where the overload was defined. If the overload was defined inside a class, than LHS is passed as 'this' to the method, and the RHS can be implicitly converted. If the method is overloaded outside of the class, than both sides can be converted. So only if the method was declared inside a class the LHS would have to be your custom type, because 'this' cannot be implicitly converted